# System.NullReferenceException: EveAI

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I have searched for the answer and have tried many different solutions but none seem to work!.

Using EveAI http://wiki.eve-id.net/EveAI

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Form1.PopulateMarketIDs()

```
private void PopulateMarketIDs()
{
    eapi.EveApi MyApi = new eapi.EveApi();
    List<int> MarketIDs = new List<int>();
    string SelectedItem;

    List<EveAI.Product.ProductType> Products = new List<EveAI.Product.ProductType>();

    foreach (string item in kryptonListBox1.Items)
    {
        SelectedItem = item;

        foreach (EveAI.Product.ProductType Prod in MyApi.EveApiCore.ProductTypes)
        {
            if (Prod.MarketGroup != null)
            {
                if (Prod.MarketGroup.ParentGroup.Name == SelectedItem)
                {
                    Products.Add(Prod);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (Prod.MarketGroup.Name == SelectedItem)
                    {
                        Products.Add(Prod);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The kryptonListBox1 contains at least one item such as "Mining Drones".
It works fine, it lists the products as it should, but when it gets to the last product (displays) and then crashes with the null error.

I am aware that it will not return anything, I have snipped out the output section of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the code to:

```
foreach (string item in kryptonListBox1.Items)
{
     foreach (EveAI.Product.ProductType Prod in MyApi.EveApiCore.ProductTypes)
     {
         if (Prod.MarketGroup != null)
         {
             if (Prod.MarketGroup.Name == item)
             {
                if (Prod.Name.Contains("Blueprint") == false)
                {
                    kryptonListBox2.Items.Add(Prod.Name);
                    Products.Add(Prod);
                }
             }
         }
     }
}

foreach (EveAI.Product.ProductType T in Products)
{
  kryptonListBox3.Items.Add(MyApi.EveApiCore.GetIdForObject(T));
}
```

And this is working great.

Answer (score 0):

i think your trouble is into the

**MyApi.EveApiCore.ProductTypes**

is this a static resource ?

else you must reference it before use it.

Comment: Yes it is referenced. using EveAI; using eapi = EveAI.Live;.  It loops through all the products fine until what it appears to be the last of the items in the given MarketGroup.

Comment: it seems you have take the last vb.net example and done it in c#, but you are iterating a different list than the example, they iterates the marketgroups you the producttypes, did you have tried the real same iteration of the example ?
is difficult to help you more without using this API and without an EVE Online Account.

Comment: The vb.net example is for making the treeview, this I have already done in c#. The code I posted is grabbing the products that are contained in the market group that is displayed in the treeview.  For some strange reason I keep getting this null error, although I cannot see any null values being passed.  This section of code does not require any API or an account. It is using static data contained within the EveAI